# Cancelling Exit window command using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, formclosing

I'm trying to use `Microsoft Interactivity InvokeCommandAction` for closing my application. I would like to ask the user whether he wishes to save before quitting, or cancel quitting.

I know that I can use a `Command` for `EventName="Closing"` and for `EventName="Closed"`. I also know that the `Closed` is being called automatically at the end of the implementation of the `Closing` event.

I tried using `MVVM light` as suggested in many posts but the either the `namespace` cannot be found or the `EventToCommand` cannot be found.

Here's my code:

**Xaml**

```
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
       <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
           <Interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  />
       </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
   </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**VM**

```
    private ICommand m_closingCommand;
    private ICommand m_exitCommand;

    public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
        get { return m_exitCommand ?? (m_exitCommand = new RelayCommand(Exit)); }
        set { m_exitCommand = value; }
    }
    public ICommand ClosingCommand
    {
        get { return m_closingCommand ?? (m_closingCommand = new RelayCommand(Closing)); }
        set { m_closingCommand = value; }
    }
    private void Exit(object parameter)
    {
        if (SaveRequired)
            SaveCommand.Execute(null);

        MarkingsManager.DisposeManager();

        Logger.CloseLogger();
        CommonCommands.CloseWindow.Execute(parameter);
    }
    private void Closing(object parameter)
    {
        if (!SaveRequired) return;
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Save Your Changes?", "Markings Clipper", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);

        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
            {
                SaveRequired = false;
                break;
            }
                case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                    return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is your question actually?

Comment: @dymanoid I guess it's `I would like to ask the user whether he wishes to save before quitting, or cancel quitting.`